# How do I change column positions in temporary table while it shows wildcard

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a table with multiple columns, and when I run it, it shows the wildcard *. Usually to change the column positions I’d go to design query in editor as I'm using SQL Server Management Studio.

However it doesn't allow me to move the columns up and down, as all it shows is wildcard and the database that it is pulled from.

How do I fix this? I've tried ORDER BY but the whole table still doesn't come out.

Comment: Do you mean columns when you say rows? Because your question does not make sense. Maybe try including a screenshot showing what you are trying to do

Comment: Yes, it's columns. Sorry.

Comment: I think my question, to be short is how to show field names, instead of just wildcard.

Comment: So are you building your query using the drag and drop Query Designer or by typing SQL?

Comment: By drag and drop, the issue is i have like 30 columns and i'd like to organize some field names close to each other. My final table is a temporary one and when i click on design query, all it shows is *

Comment: How are you "running" your table? Where exactly are you seeing `*`? Could you provide more details please? (For one, stop using the query designer - use a query window.)

Comment: Sounds like Aerox is correct that the user is using the Query Designer. There is no way that I know of that you can change the order of the columns in the designer for the specific table. Some of our developers asked me the same thing and after lots of searching there is no answer.

Comment: The easiest way is to write your query in a query window and don't rely on the query builder. It might be a little bit slower at first but soon you will actually learn how to write t-sql and it will be faster to write and faster to execute.

Comment: While you're starting to get used to writing SQL, it might be useful to write your query like `SELECT      FROM MyTable` and then copy and paste the results of this query to fill in the blank between the SELECT and FROM:
`SELECT sc.[name] 
FROM sys.columns sc JOIN sys.tables st ON sc.[object_id] = st.[object_id]
WHERE st.[name] = 'MyTable' `